# jQuery, delay link replacing iframe target

Tags: jquery

I have a simple grid layout with 4 thumbnails, each with a link inside that changes the target of a single iframe that sits at the top of my page. These work fine, but I want to add a slight delay to the iframe's target changing to allow the page to scroll to the top after each click.

Here is my iframe code;

```
<iframe id="video-frame" name="video-frame" width="560" height="315" src="[youtube-url]" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is my play button code (Of which there are 4, each with different href values;

```
<a class="play-button" href="[youtube-url]">&nbsp;</a>
```

and this is my jQuery code that scrolls to the page to the top on each `.play-button` click

```
$('.play-button').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
    $('#video-frame').attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

My issue is that the changing of the iframe src causes the scroll to be glitchy so I need to add a 650ms delay to the changing of the iframe src so the scroll has finished

Comment: Which function are you adding the delay to

Comment: @code I'm trying to delay the `$('#video-frame').attr......` part of the function

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is delay running a function you can try a function like :

```
$('.play-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
    setInterval(function () {$('#video-frame').attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));}, 650);        
});
```

The set interval will run a function after the given time **650** in our case meaning 650ms. Try it out and let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Does it wait before running the function?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. The iframe src doesn't change at all.

Comment: I edited my answer a little by adding preventDefault but what do your href values look like?

Comment: Your edited answer didn't work either. The href values are YouTube embed URL's https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXX for example